# angulario rxjs transform http result

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a observable json result from a webservice like this for example:

```
{"persons": [
    {"id":1, fname:"John", lname:"Doe"},
    {"id":2, fname:"Bill", lname:"Doe"},
    ...
]}
```

How can I transform the elements of the persons array ?
For example to generate this structure:

```
{"persons": [
    {"id":1, fname:"John", lname:"Doe", name:"Jon Doe"},
    {"id":2, fname:"Bill", lname:"Doe", name:'Bill Doe"},
    ...
]}
```

Probably a stupid question, but I'm just starting with rxjs and can't figure it out myself;
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us the code you have written to try and do this so far.

Comment: You should read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because we don't intend to do your work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use rxjs map operator. 
If res is your result you should do something like this

```
res.persons = res.persons.map(d => {
  return {
       id: d.id
       fname : d.fname,
       lname : d.lname,
       name : d.fname + ' ' + d.lname
  };
});
```

Also don't forget to include map operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```